# For Loop Not Respecting Continue Command

Tags: python, for-loop, continue

The problem I'm having is that the `continue` command is skipping inconsistently. It skips the numerical output `ebitda` but puts the incorrect `ticker` next to it. Why is this? If I make the ticker just `phm` an input it should skip, it correctly prints an empty list `[]` but when an invalid ticker is placed next to a valid one, the confusion starts happening.

```
import requests

ticker = ['aapl', 'phm', 'mmm']
ebitda = []


for i in ticker:

    r_EV=requests.get('https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/'+i+'?formatted=true&crumb=8ldhetOu7RJ&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=defaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com')
    r_ebit = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + i + '?formatted=true&crumb=B2JsfXH.lpf&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=incomeStatementHistory%2CcashflowStatementHistory%2CbalanceSheetHistory%2CincomeStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CcashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CbalanceSheetHistoryQuarterly%2Cearnings&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com%27')

    data = r_EV.json()
    data1 = r_ebit.json()

    if data1['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly']['balanceSheetStatements'][0].get('totalCurrentAssets') == None:
        continue #skips certain ticker if no Total Current Assets available (like for PHM)

    ebitda_data = data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['financialData']
    ebitda_dict = ebitda_data['ebitda']
    ebitda.append(ebitda_dict['raw']) #navigates to dictionairy where ebitda is stored

ebitda_formatted = dict(zip(ticker, ebitda))

print(ebitda_formatted)
# should print {'aapl': 73961996288, 'mmm': 8618000384}
# NOT: {'aapl': 73961996288, 'phm': 8618000384}
```

Comment: You didn't remove `phm` from `ticker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `continue` works just fine. You produce this list:

```
[73961996288, 8618000384]
```

However, you then zip that list with `ticker`, which still has 3 elements in it, including `'phm'`. `zip()` stops when one of the iterables is empty, so you produce the following tuples:

```
>>> ebitda
[73961996288, 8618000384]
>>> ticker
['aapl', 'phm', 'mmm']
>>> zip(ticker, ebitda)
[('aapl', 73961996288), ('phm', 8618000384)]
```

If you are *selectively* adding  `ebitda` values to a list, you'd also have to record what `ticker` values you processed:

```
used_ticker.append(i)
```

and use that new list.

Or you could just *start* with an empty `ebitda_formatted` dictionary and add to that in the loop:

```
ebitda_formatted[i] = ebitda_dict['raw']
```